# sql query to list columns without groupby/aggregate

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

my two tables look like this

shop table

```
buyer   timeArrived               billed     paid

ABC     2013-02-08 10:30:00       60$        45$
CTS     2013-02-18 10:30:00       100$       80$
ABC     2012-03-11 10:30:00       60$        40$
MNT     2012-02-08 10:30:00       100$       60$
CTS     2012-03-11 10:30:00       60$        40$
```

buyer_t table

```
buyer

ABC
MNT
CTS
GH
```

to search for a buyer when he was 'last seen', i query from buyer table on to shop table
like

```
SELECT
 v.buyer,
 MAX(s.timeArrived) AS LastSeen
 FROM buyer_t AS b
 INNER JOIN shop as s ON b.buyer = s.buyer
 where 
 l.buyer = 'ABC' or l.buyer = 'CTS'
 GROUP BY b.buyer;
```

it is fine to know when ABC and CTS shopped
but how do i get 'billed' and 'paid' columns as well

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT
 b.buyer,
 s.*
FROM buyer_t AS b
INNER JOIN shop as s ON b.buyer = s.buyer
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT buyer, MAX(timeArrived) AS LastSeen
   FROM shop
   GROUP BY buyer
) AS s2  ON s.buyer = s2.buyer
        AND s.timeArrived = s2.lastSeen
WHERE s.buyer IN ('ABC', 'CTS');
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dae0e/3)

This will give you:

```
| BUYER |                     TIMEARRIVED | BILLED | PAID |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|   ABC | February, 08 2013 10:30:00+0000 |    60$ |  45$ |
|   CTS | February, 18 2013 10:30:00+0000 |   100$ |  80$ |
```

---

**Or:** Since you are using SQL Server 2005, then you can use the [ranking function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY ...)` to do this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
      s.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.buyer
                        ORDER BY timeArrived DESC) AS Rownumber
    FROM buyer_t AS b
    INNER JOIN shop as s ON b.buyer = s.buyer
    WHERE s.buyer IN ('ABC', 'CTS')
) 
SELECT Buyer, TimeArrived, Billed, Paid
FROM CTE 
WHERE Rownumber = 1;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo for SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dae0e/8)

Comment: @user1944477 There is no `v` alias in your query, try `s.buyer` or `b.buyer` instead.

Comment: @user1944477 Yes it hives you the most recent, the max date is the most recent date.

Comment: SURE but im not able to accept the answer its not accepting it shows 4 but comes back to 3.. :(

Comment: @user1944477 Its OK, this how things work here in Stackoverflow :)